# Quickest way to split a delimited String in Java

Tags: java, performance, efficiency, sorting

I am building a Comparator that provides multi-column sort capability on a delimited String.
I am currently using the split method from String class as my preferred choice for splitting the raw String into tokens.

Is this the best performing way to convert the raw String into a String array? I will be sorting millions of rows so I think approach matters.

It seems to run fine and is very easy, but unsure if there's a faster way in java.

Here is how the sort works in my Comparator:

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {

    String[] aValues = a.split(_delimiter, _columnComparators.length);
    String[] bValues = b.split(_delimiter, _columnComparators.length);
    int result = 0;

    for( int index : _sortColumnIndices ) {
        result = _columnComparators[index].compare(aValues[index], bValues[index]);
        if(result != 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

After benchmarking the various approaches, believe it or not, the split method was the quickest using the latest version of java. You can download my completed comparator here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/multicolumnrowcomparator/

Comment: I will point out that the nature of the answer to this question depends on the implementation of the jvm.  The behavior of strings (sharing a common backing array in OpenJDK, but not in OracleJDK) differs.  This difference can have significant impacts on splitting strings and the creation of substrings, along with garbage collection and memory leaks.  How big are these arrays? How are you doing it now? Would you consider an answer that makes for a new Stringish type rather than actual Java Strings?

Comment: In particular look at [StringTokenizer nextToken](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/StringTokenizer.java#StringTokenizer.nextToken%28%29) which eventually calls [package private String constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#643).  Compare this to the changes documented in [Changes to String internal representation made in Java 1.7.0_06](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/)

Comment: The array size depends on the number of columns so it is variable. This multi-column Comparator is passed as a parameter like so: ExternalSort.mergeSortedFiles(fileList, new File("BigFile.csv"), _comparator, Charset.defaultCharset(), false );  The External sort routine will sort the whole row string, it is actually the comparator that does the splitting and sorting based on the sort columns

Comment: I'd consider looking at lucene's tokenizers. Lucene can be used as just a powerful text analysis library that performs well for both simple and complex tasks

Comment: Consider Apache Commons Lang's `StringUtils.split[PreserveAllTokens](text, delimiter)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've written a quick and dirty benchmark test for this.  It compares 7 different methods, some of which require specific knowledge of the data being split.

For basic general purpose splitting, Guava Splitter is 3.5x faster than String#split() and I'd recommend using that.  Stringtokenizer is slightly faster than that and splitting yourself with indexOf is twice as fast as again.

For the code and more info see https://web.archive.org/web/20210613074234/http://demeranville.com/battle-of-the-tokenizers-delimited-text-parser-performance
(original link is dead and corresponding site does not appear to exist anymore)

Comment: I'm just curious what JDK you were using... and if it was 1.6, I'd be most interested in seeing a recap of your results in 1.7.

Comment: it was 1.6 I think.  The code is there as a JUnit test if you want to run it in 1.7.  Note String.split performs regex matching, which is always going to be slower than splitting on a single defined character.

Comment: Yep, however for 1.6, the StringTokenizer (and similar) code calls a String.substring() that does O(1) creation of the new string by using the same backing array.  This was changed in 1.7 to make a copy of the necessary part of the backing array rather for O(n).  This could have a singicncant impact in your results making the difference between the split and StringTokenizer less (slowing down everything that used substring before).

Comment: all the test strings have a single delimiter.  I imagine if you ran the tests over different data you'd see slightly different results.

Comment: Certainly true.  The thing is the way that StringTokenizer works has gone from "to create a new string assign 3 integers" to "to create a new string, do an array copy of the data" which will change how fast that part is.  The difference between the various approaches may be less now and it would be interesting (if for no other reason than its interesting) to do a followup with Java 1.7.

Comment: that's a job for monday :)

Comment: Thanks for that article! Very useful and will use to benchmark various approaches.

Comment: Nice post - confirms my anecdotal timings on `split()`.  Didn't realize that Java7 changed things on substring - it that something that can be controlled via a JVM argument?  Also, see my answer, as OP probably doesn't want to split his Strings multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

As @Tom writes, an indexOf type approach is faster than `String.split()`, since the latter deals with regular expressions and has a lot of extra overhead for them.

However, one algorithm change that might give you a super speedup.  Assuming that this Comparator is going to be used to sort your ~100,000 Strings, do not write the `Comparator<String>`.  Because, in the course of your sort, the same String will likely be compared *multiple* times, so you will split it *multiple* times, etc...

Split all the Strings *once* into String[]s, and have a `Comparator<String[]>` sort the String[].  Then, at the end, you can combine them all together.

Alternatively, you could also use a Map to cache the String -> String[] or vice versa.  e.g. (sketchy)  Also note, you are trading memory for speed, hope you have lotsa RAM

```
HashMap<String, String[]> cache = new HashMap();

int compare(String s1, String s2) {
   String[] cached1 = cache.get(s1);
   if (cached1  == null) {
      cached1 = mySuperSplitter(s1):
      cache.put(s1, cached1);
   }
   String[] cached2 = cache.get(s2);
   if (cached2  == null) {
      cached2 = mySuperSplitter(s2):
      cache.put(s2, cached2);
   }

   return compareAsArrays(cached1, cached2);  // real comparison done here
}
```

Comment: It would require modification to the External Sort code which can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/externalsortinginjava/

Comment: Probably easiest to use a Map then.  See edit.

Comment: Given that this is part of an external sort engine (to deal with far more data than can possibly fit in available memory), I was really going after an efficient "splitter" (yes, it is wasteful to split same String repeatedly, hence my original need to do this as fast as possible)

Comment: Briefly browsing the ExternalSort code, it looks like if you cleared your cache at the end (or start) of every `sortAndSave()` call then you should not run out of memory due to a huge cache.  IMO, the code should have a few extra hooks like firing events or calling do-nothing protected methods that users like you could override.  (Also, it should not be all static methods so that they can *do* this)  You might want to contact the authors and file a request.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this benchmarks](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/splitting_tokenisation_performance.shtml#.UrRtF6qp0_E), StringTokenizer is faster for splitting strings but it doesn't return an array which makes it less convenient.

If you need to sort millions of rows I'd recommend using a RDBMS.

Comment: That was under JDK 1.6 - things in strings are fundamentally different in 1.7 - see http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/ (in particular, creating a substring is not O(1) anymore but rather O(n)).  The link notes that in 1.6 Pattern.split used different String creating than String.substring()) - see code linked in comment above to follow the StringTokenizer.nextToken() and the package private constructor it had access to.

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I use for parsing large (1GB+) tab-delimited files. It has far less overhead than `String.split()`, but is limited to `char` as a delimiter. If anyone has a faster method, I'd like to see it. This can also be done over `CharSequence` and `CharSequence.subSequence`, but that requires implementing `CharSequence.indexOf(char)` (refer to the package method [`String.indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount, char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount, int fromIndex)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.indexOf%28char%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%29) if interested).

```
public static String[] split(final String line, final char delimiter)
{
    CharSequence[] temp = new CharSequence[(line.length() / 2) + 1];
    int wordCount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = line.indexOf(delimiter, 0); // first substring

    while (j >= 0)
    {
        temp[wordCount++] = line.substring(i, j);
        i = j + 1;
        j = line.indexOf(delimiter, i); // rest of substrings
    }

    temp[wordCount++] = line.substring(i); // last substring

    String[] result = new String[wordCount];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, result, 0, wordCount);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked this vs String.split() ? If so, how does it compare?

Comment: @JayElston On a 900MB file, it reduced the split time from 7.7 seconds to 6.2 seconds, so around 20% faster. It is still the slowest part of my floating-point matrix parsing. I'm guessing that much of the remaining time is array allocation. It might be possible to cut the matrix allocation out by using a tokenizer-based approach with an offset in the method - that would start to look more like the method I cited above the code.